# How do I stop AppBarConfiguration from switching the hamburger icon into the back arrow?

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-navigation

How do I get the hamburger icon back for the navigation drawer? the `AppBarConfiguration` changes it into a back arrow, why is that?

This is my code below:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    init_v3();
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.home, R.id.nav_tasks)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add all the fragments that you don't want the up/back button to show up in the `appBarConfiguration`

In your example, this up/back button won't show up in `R.id.nav_tasks` & `R.id.home` fragments as you already added them. >> if you have more fragments, then add them into the below separating between them with comma.

And to show up the Drawer burger icon, you need to call [`setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/AppBarConfiguration.Builder#setOpenableLayout(androidx.customview.widget.Openable))

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                                         R.id.home,  
                                         R.id.nav_tasks)
                                         .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                                         .build();
```

Comment: i want the hamburger icon to show up instead of the up/back button, how do i fix that?

Comment: @nucci96 you can call `setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)` .. I edited the answer with it.. just change the `drawer_layout` according that exist in your layout file

Comment: all that does is make my app crash

Comment: @nucci96 Please update the question with the xml layout and the crash report

Comment: actually you were right, i made an error, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that  if you feel like this solved your issue.. Thanks to accept the answer